# React: problems with a cards

Tags: css, reactjs

I am new to React and I have been having some problems with the css of some cards that I show on my website. I have tried in many ways but without success.

I have the parent component:

```js
import React, { EventHandler } from "react";
import ModelOptionList from "./ModelOptionsList";
import Step1 from "./Step1";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

export default class ModelType extends React.Component<any, any> {
  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      modelName: null,
      isCustom: false,
      isDisabled: true,
      filesubidos: [],
      RowCount: 0,
      iList: 0,
      modelID: 0
    };
    this.readProps = this.readProps.bind(this);
    this.changeState = this.changeState.bind(this);
    this.click =this.click.bind(this);
  }

  readProps(modelName: string) {
    this.setState({
      modelName: modelName,
      isCustom: false,
      isDisabled: false
    });
    console.log(this.state.modelName);
  }

  changeState() {
    this.setState({
      isCustom: !this.state.isCustom,
      modelName: ""
    });
    this.click();
  }

  click(){
    if(this.state.isCustom==false){
      this.setState({isDisabled:false});
    }
    else{
      this.setState({isDisabled:true});
    }
  }

  render() {
    let g: string;
    return (
      <div className="container panel flu">
        <Step1 />
        <div className="wizard-content">
          <h2>Type of model to be created</h2>
          <p className="paragraph--large">
            Please select the type of model that you want to create
          </p>
          <div className="card-container">
            <ModelOptionList readProps={this.readProps} />
            <div
              className={this.state.isCustom==true?"card card-panel card__check card--checkbox card--checkbox--checked card--checkbox waves-effect waves-light":"card card-panel card--checkbox waves-effect waves-light material-icons card__check"}
              tabIndex={0}
              onClick={this.changeState}
            ><i className="material-icons card__check">done</i>
              <div className="card__main-content center-align">
                <i className="material-icons card__icon">cloud</i>
                <div className="card-title">Custom Model</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="wizard-footer">
          <Link to="/home">
            <button className="btn button--ghost button--with-icon-left waves-effect waves--orange-light">
              <i className="material-icons button__icon">clear</i>
              <span className="button__text">Cancel</span>
            </button>
          </Link>
          <Link
            className={this.state.isDisabled == true ? "disabledLink" : ""}
            to={{
              pathname: "/steps/modelfile/" + this.state.modelName,
              state: {
                isCustom: this.state.isCustom,
                filesubidos: this.state.filesubidos,
                RowCount: this.state.RowCount,
                iList: this.state.iList,
                modelID: this.state.modelID
              }
            }}
          >
            <button
              className="btn button--primary button--with-icon-right waves-effect waves--orange-dark"
              disabled={this.state.isDisabled}
            >
              <i className="material-icons button__icon">
                keyboard_arrow_right
              </i>
              <span className="button__text">Next</span>
            </button>
          </Link>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

With the function changeState I get that my card (which is independent of those that are siblings) I achieve that when clicking on it the corresponding css is activated and the next button is activated and that if I click on it again (with the css being active ) the css is deactivated and the next button is also deactivated and that if I click outside that card (that is not a click on the others) the css and the next button remain active, and also if having selected the independent card I click on one of the cards that are siblings the css to which I clicked is activated and the css is removed from the previous one.

This is what I also want to achieve with the sister cards. I hope I have explained well and that you can help me. Thanks in advance.

I leave the other components react that I have

```js
import React from "react";
import ModelOptionCard from "./ModelOptionCard";
import { IModel } from "../Home/IModel";
import models from "../../services/models";

export default class ModelOptionList extends React.Component<any, any> {
  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      availableModels: [],
      stateAvailable:false
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    let institutionID2 = 2;
    models.templateModelsAvailable(institutionID2).then(res => {
      this.setState({ availableModels: res });
    });
  }
  render() {
    console.log(this.state.availableModels);
    return this.state.availableModels.map((model: string, i: number) => (
      <ModelOptionCard
        key={i}
        ModelName={model}
        ModelID={i}
        readProps={this.props.readProps}
      />
    ));
  }
}
interface IModelDefaultListProps {
  models: IModel[];
}
interface IState {
  modelsdefault: IModel[];
  models: IModel[];
  availableModels: IModel[];
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

With the modelClick function of the following code, the only thing I achieve is that when selecting a sister card the css is put on and that when selecting another sibling card the css is removed from the previous one and it is put to the one that I clicked.

```js
import React from "react";
import { directive } from "@babel/types";
export default class ModelOptionCard extends React.Component<IProps, IState> {
  constructor(props: IProps) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      active: false
    };
    this.modelClick = this.modelClick.bind(this);
    this.handleOutsideClick = this.handleOutsideClick.bind(this);
  }
  modelClick() {
    if(this.state.active==false){
      document.addEventListener('click', this.handleOutsideClick, false);
      let modelName = this.props.ModelName;
      this.setState({ active: true });

      this.props.readProps(modelName);
    }
    else{
      document.removeEventListener('click', this.handleOutsideClick, false);
      this.setState({ active: false});
    }
  }

  handleOutsideClick(){
    this.modelClick();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className={this.state.active==true? "card card-panel card--checkbox card--checkbox--checked waves-effect waves-light":"card card-panel card--checkbox waves-effect waves-light"} tabIndex={0} key={this.props.ModelID} onClick={this.modelClick}><i className="material-icons card__check">done</i>
        <div className="card__main-content center-align">
          <i className="material-icons card__icon">cloud</i>
          <div className="card-title">{this.props.ModelName}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
interface IProps {
  ModelName: string;
  ModelID: number;
  key: number;
  readProps: (modelName: string) => void;
}
interface IState {
  active: boolean;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```